# How to duplicate the database using Talend?

Tags: etl, talend

I am new to Talend and trying to duplicate the database in MySQL before I start migration from one database to another database using Talend for Integration tool version 5.5.1.

Here is the [page on the talend help](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20819579)  where I found the command which I have written below

From database X to database X
Depending on your OS and architecture, perform one of the following commands. Talend-Studio-linux-gtk-x86 as well as Talend-Studio-win32-x86.exe are only given as examples. Use the actual .exe name that you can find at the root of the NEW CommandLine directory.

As explained in the prerequisites, to prevent the structure of the source database from being edited during the migration process, you need to duplicate this database and use this duplicated database as source database in the migration script. For further information about database backup, see the Backing up the administration database (MySQL, H2, MS SQL Server, or Oracle).

I am running this command in command prompt :-

```
 TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe -nosplash -application org.talend.repository.TalendMigration 
 -consoleLog -data migration-workspace -sourceUrl jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test 
 -sourceUser root -sourcePasswd root -targetUrl  jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test1 
 -targetUser root -targetPasswd root -vmargs -Xss5m -Xms64m -Xmx1024m
```

but I am getting some error like :-

```
!SESSION 2014-09-18 16:42:22.690 -----------------------------------------------
 eclipse.buildId=unknown
 java.version=1.7.0_67
 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
 BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
 Framework arguments:  -application org.talend.repository.TalendMigration -sourceUrl   
 jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test -sourceUser root -sourcePasswd root -targetUrl 
 jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test1 -targetUser root -targetPasswd root
 Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -application  
 org.talend.repository.TalendMigration -consoleLog -data migration-workspace -sourceUrl 
 jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test -sourceUser root -sourcePasswd root -targetUrl   
  jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test1 -targetUser root -targetPasswd root

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-18 16:42:24.174
```

Answer (score 0):

Talend is not a command line tools. It gives access to a studio where you can design your data integration jobs.
If you want to start the studio, just run  TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe (on windows 64bit)

When your data integration jobs are designed, they can be exported as batch jobs. Then you will be able to run a command to execute the job.

For getting started with Talend Open Studio, please see their [official web site](http://www.talend.com/) and all the resources available on [Talend Forge](http://www.talendforge.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you should look in to my updated post for the command, there is a talend help link where you can find the command.

Comment: The link you give point to an article that explain how to upgrade your Talend installation, but I'm not sure that it is what you want to do.

Comment: What is your first need ? Do you want to migrate some data from one mySQL DB to another mySQL DB ? Or simply upgrade your Talend products ?

Comment: I do not know why link is not working for you but using same link I can open that post, anyway I have copied there on question whatever is written there, so it means we can achieve this by using command prompt. I just wanted to move full database from SQL server to MySQL but right now I am trying to just duplicate the database.

Comment: The link you had in your post points to Talend Enterprise, which uses like 5-10 tables. It will migrate ONLY those tables.

Comment: @Sharad : please explain what you want to do : upgrade your Talend Enterprise installation or migrate some data from one mySQL DB to another mySQL DB ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use command line in talend then you can use **tSystem** component and can paste the mysql command line query in **tSystem** command box and run the job.